# Eclipse and proxy

Tags: eclipse, proxy, m2e, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I run my Eclipse on a Linux computer behind a company proxy. This proxy does not need authentication, it simply needs to be set. But in Eclipse *some* functionalities can't connect to the Internet. When I check the same URL with e.f. `curl` and the same proxy settings everything works fine.

I defined the proxy:

- in /etc/environment, both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`
- in Eclipse in Window / Preferences / Network connection / Manual. For http and https, not for socks
- in settings.xml, I can see from the preferences that this file gets applied

Eclipse can connect to the Internet:

- in the Marketplace
- for update checks and Installation

Eclipse is unable to reach the Internet:

- in the "Web Browser" view
- in m2e

Any ideas where I missed a special setting ? I do all of this in STS 3.9, which has Eclipse 4.7

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the browser view, but m2e/Maven uses proxy settings that are defined in the settings.xml file for Maven.

In Eclipse/STS, you can specify which settings.xml file m2e should use in the preferences for the Maven support.

Comment: Dankeschön for your input, I forgot to mention (and therefore edited my question) that the proxy is set in settings.xml

Comment: And I assume that you refer to that exact settings file from the Maven preferences in Eclipse/STS, right? And does a Maven build on the command line works fine with those proxy settings?